# Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_STRING' or `T_VARIABLE' or `'{'' or `'$''

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm getting a

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_STRING' or `T_VARIABLE' or `'{'' or `'$'' in C:\wamp\www\...\taxonomy-activities.php on line 22
```

I have following code on Line 22:

```
    <?php $tag_extra_fields_Colour = get_option(Activities_Extras_Colour);
        $activites_color=$tag_extra_fields_Colour[$term->term_id]['Activities_ColourField'];
    ?>  
    <h3 style="color:<?php echo $activites_color ?>">Activities</h3>
```

What could be wrong here?
Its a WP custom taxonomy page, where I need to display a value of the custom field.

Comment: Which of those is line 22? Do you need to quote out what you're passing in to `get_option`, perhaps?

Comment: This is line 22 -> $activites_color=$tag_extra_fields_Colour[$term->term_id]['Activities_ColourField'];

Comment: the code you've provided looks like it's OK - possibly there's an error on a preceding line. Could you add the rest of the code to the question?

Comment: why this is closed? Everyone may have this kind of error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have put **Activities_Extras_Colour** as a string like:

```
<?php $tag_extra_fields_Colour = get_option('Activities_Extras_Colour');
```

Comment: Hi, tried this as well.. I still get the same error.

Comment: That's odd. I pasted the code to my development site and all I got was a Notice "Undefined variable: term", so no Parse error like you have.

Comment: @user850010 - I expect the error occurs on a line before the code block he's provided; there'll be an unclosed quote or something similar, probably.